# How can I contact Battle Net?

Tags: battle.net

Everybody has put down the call center but what I really want is the email, as I'm  a student and I  have a tight budget which sadly means that calling isn't an option.

I have sent in two support tickets for the authenticator to be removed (I have a new phone and the authenticator is gone). I gave them my ID photo but its been a month with no answer whatsoever and you cant get real support unless you log in which I can't, due to needing the authenticator.

Edit: I've been with Battle Net for about 5 years now, I understand their support page but login is necessary to get most support. I just need a better option.

What can I do?

Comment: There's a whole Support Ticket system on their website, including live chat and e-mail. Did you even check the support page?

Comment: yes that is true they have that but you need to login to get the live chat and such

Answer (score 2):

You can use the callback option so the call doesn't cost anything or you can try making a new ticket. [You can do both here](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/help/?utm_campaign=BlizzardCSEU&utm_medium=posting&utm_source=external-twitter&utm_content=contactproduct/battlenet/316/977/solution)

Answer (score 1):

You can try tweeting directly to Blizzard Support. Their Twitter account is [@BlizzardCS](http://twitter.com/BlizzardCS).

Comment: um I'm a weird teen, I don't have twitter

Comment: It's free to create a twitter account.

Comment: true but never saw the point in it...

Comment: @InkFire the point is this- contacting blizz. Edit: nevermind, [I did that for you](https://twitter.com/ardaozkal/status/742197777816551424)

Comment: @InkFire For the 1 entire minute it would take to set up a twitter, even for this single purpose would it not be worth for a chance to get your account back? You gotta help yourself a little dude!

Comment: thank you ardaozkal for asking up ill try the call back thing but ill probably still get charged, the phone companies love finding ways to charge extra where I live. they once charged me for calling somebody supposedly long distance when they were just a block away on their cell